# Это какой-то новый формат сохранения ресурсов в apk?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

Тут на днях попалось приложение из очень странным содержимым в папке res/values а именно файл arrays.xml содержал в себе такое:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="fonts_size" />
<style name="heightSys" />
<style name="langs" />
<style name="langsValues" />
<style name="pref_common_bread_unit_titles" />
<style name="pref_common_bread_unit_values" />
<style name="profileActiveHint" />
<style name="profileTargetHint" />
<style name="proversion_subscriptions" />
<style name="size_coef" />
<style name="weightSys" />
</resources>
```

Это что-то новенькое? Ибо декомпиляторы apk покачто отказываются назад собирать apk. Зарание спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобались мы с этим. Это неправильная декомпиляция ресурсов apk файла с помощью apktool.jar собранных под новые платформы. Лечится это с помощью [плагина](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=557858&view=findpost&p=78316209) из форума 4pda. За что отдельное спасибо автору плагина. Надеюсь, кому-то поможет этот ответ.